# Chartr() elimina los documentos dentro del corpus - R

Tags: r, nlp

Estoy usando *R 3.3.1* en *Windows 10*. Tengo un *set* de 3099 archivos *txt* que estoy usando para minería de texto con el paquete `tm()`.

El código estaba funcionando perfectamente, pero repentinamente comenzó a fallar...

Después de intentar quitar los acentos de mi corpus, los documentos desaparecen.

Perseguí el problema hasta la siguiente línea de código, la cual usaba para quitar los acentos:

```
setwd("C:/txt")
library(tm) 
cname <- file.path("C:", "txt")
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname))
docs <- tm_map(docs, tolower)
docs
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: **3099**
**docs <- chartr("áéíóú", "aeiou", docs)**   # remove accents
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))   # back to a corpus
docs
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: **3**
```

Como pueden ver, repentinamente los 3099 documentos, ahora son solo 3, y esos 3 estan en blanco.

No se generó ningún error, ni alerta. Lo más extraño es que este código estaba funcionando.

¿Alguien puede orientarme con este problema? Al no dar error, no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: La pregunta debe estar en castellano para que pueda ser respondida.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está redactada en inglés.

Comment: Fue editada al español,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes usar `chartr` directamente con un objeto `VCorpus`. Una vez creado los corpus con `tm` luego utiliza la API de transformación del paquete vía `tm_map`.

```
library(tm)
docs <- c("esto sí es un documento.", "éste no lo es.")
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))
print(corp[[1]]$content)
[1] "esto sí es un documento."

removeAccents <- content_transformer(function(x) chartr("áéíóú", "aeiou", x))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeAccents)
print(corp[[1]]$content)
[1] "esto si es un documento."
```

Puedes ver los objetos intermedios usando la función `str` de R.

Comment: Esto lo soluciono!
Lo unico, que tuve que eliminar la linea que vuelve a generar el corpus, porque ahora generaba error. 
Pero solucionado eso, ya no desaparecen los documentos y a la inspeccion los acentos ya no estan!

No entiendo porque comenzo a fallar,, pero ahora esta solucionado!
Impecable, muchas gracias!